# Re-run testsuites with Robot framework and Ride with different login information

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have done some test suites with Robot framework and Ride including several testcases
which requires starting of web browser and user login to website.

Without just copying the testsuites/testcase and hardcode other browser and user login,
how can I re-use and re-run existing ones just changing first the used browser,
then re-run the same with user2?

Test Cases are something like:

```
Open Browser - Chrome
#Open Browser - Firefox 
Login1
#Login2
Do something....
#For loop already used inside the testcase
FOR    ${var}    IN    IN RANGE    1    10
    Exit For Loop If    Some condition is true
    ${var} =    Evaluate    ${var} + 1
    #do something until condition is true
    Scroll Element Into View    test_element
    Set Focus To Element    test_element
END
Continue test case....
```

Keywords:

```
Open Browser - Chrome
Open Browser    https://test.testpage.com/  chrome
......
Open Browser - Firefox
Open Browser    https://test.testpage.com/  ff
......
Login1
Wait Until Element Is Visible   test_Login_username 
Input Text  test_Login_username test.id1
Input Password  test_Login_password test.password1
Click Button    test_Login_LoginBtn
.....
Login2
Wait Until Element Is Visible   test_Login_username 
Input Text  test_Login_username test.id2
Input Password  test_Login_password test.password2
Click Button    test_Login_LoginBtn
```

I know that for example I could set the browsers inside for-loop like

```
*** Variables ***
@{BROWSERS}       Chrome    ff
```

And the loop them inside the testcase like

```
FOR    ${Browser}    IN    @{BROWSERS}
    Open Browser    https://test.testpage.com/    ${Browser}
END
```

But the broblem in this is, that you can't use nested for-loops??

Comment: I do not see any need to mention and tag RIDE. This is a coding/structure problem. The tag robotframework-ide can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

It's true you can't have nested loops in RF. It's also true that there's an easy workaround as [documented in the user guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops):

```
*** Keywords ***
Handle Table
    [Arguments]    @{table}
    FOR    ${row}    IN    @{table}
        Handle Row    @{row}
    END

Handle Row
    [Arguments]    @{row}
    FOR    ${cell}    IN    @{row}
        Handle Cell    ${cell}
    END
```

Your code examples seems a bit messy to me, so I won't go into using these as an example. But in general, I'd:

1. create a keyword with a for loop that represents some test steps
2. implement a test case where I loop over different browsers executing the keyword from 1. inside the for loop